# Increase Performance of WhenEvent in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics, event-detection

I'm trying to reset the value of functions $u_{i}$ when they reach a threshold $θ$. Below the threshold, they evolve according to a simple differential equation. The $r_{i}$ resets the derivative to zero for a while (refractory period of a neuron), but I doubt that's relevant to my question.

[`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) is really slow when the number of events is increased (which can be done by decreasing `recovery`). I don't understand why an artificial discontinuity would make this code slower. Here is a minimal example where all $u_{i}$ are the same:

```
recovery = 0.01; θ = 0.5; n = 50; T = 2;
s = ConstantArray[{}, n];

AbsoluteTiming[
 sol = NDSolve[Table[With[{i = i}, {
  Subscript[u, i]'[t] == (-Subscript[u, i][t] + 10^3) Boole[Subscript[r, i][t] < t], 
  Subscript[r, i][0] == 0, 
  Subscript[u, i][0] == 0, 

  WhenEvent[
   Subscript[u, i][t] > θ, {Subscript[u, i][t] -> 0, 
   AppendTo[s[[i]], t], 
   Subscript[r, i][t] -> t + recovery}]}],
 {i, n}], 

  Table[{Subscript[u, i], Subscript[r, i]}, {i, n}] // Flatten, {t, 0, T}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> Table[Subscript[r, i], {i, n}]];
 ]

Length[s // First] (*number of events*)

(*{65.485, Null}*)
(*191*)
```

What could be causing this, and is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: The use of `WhenEvent` with `recovery` so much smaller than `T` forces the `NDSolve` timesteps to be very small. For the parameters chosen, `NDSolve` takes `1719` timesteps.  When `WhenEvent` is disabled, the number of timesteps drops to `49`.  This accounts for a factor of `35` in runtime.  But, there is another factor of `20` to be accounted for.  Probably, it is due to computing the precise times at which `WhenEvent` is triggered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `Boole` worries me, so here's an approach that avoids it.  I define another `DiscreteVariable` for each equation called `Subscript[sw,i][t]` that is either 0 or 1 and acts as a switch on the `Subscript[u, i]'[t]` equations.  I also add another `WhenEvent` that turns the switch back off at time `t==Subscript[r, i][t]`.

```
AbsoluteTiming[sol = NDSolve[Table[With[{i = i}, {
  Subscript[u, i]'[t] == Subscript[sw, i][t] (-Subscript[u, i][t] + 10^3),
  Subscript[r, i][0] == 0, Subscript[u, i][0] == 0, Subscript[sw, i][0] == 1, 
  WhenEvent[Subscript[u, i][t] > θ, 
    {Subscript[u, i][t] -> 0, AppendTo[s[[i]], t],
     Subscript[r, i][t] -> t + recovery, Subscript[sw, i][t] -> 0}],
  WhenEvent[t == Subscript[r, i][t], Subscript[sw, i][t] -> 1]
 }], {i, n}],
 Table[{Subscript[u, i], Subscript[r, i], Subscript[sw, i]}, {i, n}] // Flatten,
 {t, 0, T}, DiscreteVariables ->
   Evaluate[Table[{Subscript[r, i], Subscript[sw, i]}, {i, n}] // Flatten]
];]

Length[s // First]

(* {18.3326, Null} *)
(* 191 *)
```

I am hoping that there's a better way though, because this still seems too slow.  I thought using `Reap` and `Sow` instead of `AppendTo` might help, but it really didn't.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 6):

This is in part some minor improvements in speed for [ChrisK](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6358/chris-k)'s good answer (+1), and in part an extended comment.  To begin, using `Subscript` variables generally is not a good idea in computations.  Also, building `Table`s inside `NDSolve` often is slow, although it does not matter much here.  With these changes, the question's code as optimized by ChrisK becomes

```
recovery = 1/100; θ = 1/2; n = 50; T = 2;
s = ConstantArray[{}, n];
var = Table[ {u[ i], r[i], sw[i]}, {i, n}] // Flatten ;
dvar = Table[{r[i][t], sw[ i][t]}, {i, n}] // Flatten;
eq = Table[With[{i = i}, {u[ i]'[t] == sw[ i][t] (- u[i][t] + 10^3), 
    r[i][0] == 0, u[i][0] == 0, sw[i][0] == 1, 
    WhenEvent[u[i][t] > θ, {u[i][t] -> 0, AppendTo[s[[i]], t], 
        r[i][t] -> t + recovery, sw[ i][t] -> 0}],
    WhenEvent[t > r[i][t], sw[i][t] -> 1]}], {i, n}];
sol = NDSolve[eq, var, {t, 0, T}, DiscreteVariables -> dvar]; // AbsoluteTiming
Length[s // First]

(* {16.8441, Null} *)
(* 191 *)
```

which gives the desired answer in about seventeen seconds.  As I noted in my earlier comment, this computation is very slow, because restarting the computation with `WhenEvent` 2*191 times results in many very small timesteps, 1791 in this case.  In contrast, the computation requires only 49 timesteps and takes only about 0.03 seconds without `WhenEvent`.

The runtime can be reduced by about 30% by using the option, `"LocationMethod" -> "LinearInterpolation"` in `WhenEvent` and requesting only modest accuracy from `NDSolve`: `AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3`.  (Nerve cells do not fire with high precision anyway.)  Doing so produces essentially the same answers as before but in about twelve seconds.  It seems likely that choosing an optimal integration `Method` will further reduce runtime.  I say this based on the observation that the solution is almost always zero, punctuated by 191 evenly spaced spikes of width `10^-3 θ`.  I tried several possibilities but only succeeded in increasing runtime.

I also tried eliminating the second `WhenEvent` by using

```
u[i]'[t] == Piecewise[ {{(- u[i][t] + 10^3), t > r[i][t]}}, 0]
```

or

```
u[i]'[t] == If[t > r[i][t], (- u[i][t] + 10^3), 0]
```

but doing so increased runtime to a bit more than forty seconds.  As noted in the question, `Boole` is slower yet, although it certainly yields the correct answer.

Finally I would remark that the OP probably intends this question as a prototype for many coupled neurons (those in the question are uncoupled) firing at different times.  To see the effect of neurons firing at different times, I used the initial condition, `u[i][0] == θ (i - 1)/n`.  Runtime increased to about 300 sec.  All this suggests that computational models not involving `NDSolve` should be investigated.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how this could be implemented without NDSolve? Is there are better way than writing my own numerical differential equation solver?

Comment: Probably, I (and others) can suggest alternatives to `NDSolve` but we need to know the mathematical expression you wish to solve numerically.  The sample problem in the question here probably is too simple, in that a symbolic solution is readily available.  I also would suggest that you close out this question by accepting one of the two answers and then asking a new question.